# What does Vyasa say about the equality shown by God between Asuras and Devas?

Tags: krishna, gods, bhagavata-purana, asuras, daitya

"Why is Lord Vishnu partial towards the Devas and impartial towards the Daityas? " was the question raised by Parikshit to Sukha Deva, for which the latter replied, "That Devas are of Sattva Guna and Asuras are of Rajo and Tamo Guna which made them lose" How does this answer help with the question raised by Parikshit? Shouldn't the answer be Dharma? How is it justified for taking the throne of Deva Lokha from Bhali ( Bhali got the throne by his good deeds ),

Comment: **[sattvat sanjayate jnanam](https://asitis.com/14/17.html):**  From the mode of goodness, real knowledge develops. Parabrahman can be realized by sattva alone.

Comment: According to Manu Smriti both Devas and Asuras are manifestations of Sattva Guna .. with only a minor difference existing between them.

Comment: Why did he support devas over Asuras? Was it because of their Sattva Guna?

Comment: Both are Sattva guna .. that's what I am saying .. so not because of Gunas. Lord Vishnu is naturally inimical to Asuras and that's why Asuras hardly worship Vishnu too. @Shashaank

Comment: Check Manu 12.48 and 12.49 and you will find that both gods and Daityas are manifestations of Sattva .. however Rakshasas are from Tamas not Sattva. @Shashaank